# How to compile and run java files from sub-directory

Tags: java, makefile

I'm trying to compile `.java` files and store them in a sub-directory called `bin`. I then want to run the generated `.class` files from the main directory. How can I do this?

Here's my Makefile:

```
# java compiler
JCC = javac

# output directory
OUTDIR = bin/

# compilation flags
JFLAGS = -g -d $(OUTDIR)

# default target entry
default: A.class B.class C.class

A.class: A.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) A.java

B.class: B.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) B.java

C.class: C.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) C.java

# To start over from scratch, type 'make clean'.
# Removes all .class files, so that the next make rebuilds them
clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTDIR)*.class
```

What I want to do:

1. make
2. java bin/A

Comment: Do you get an error? If so please provide this

Comment: There are better build tools for Java than Make. Check out Gradle, Maven, Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the `bin` directory as the *classpath* of the JVM, using the `-cp` option

```
java -cp bin A
```

`A` being the fully qualified name of the class to run.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Is there way to add the classpath while compiling? I tried changing the JFLAGS variable to ``JFLAGS = -g -d $(OUTDIR) -cp bin`` but then I get errors while compiling

Comment: The classpath you specify during compilation is the one used to resolve class names during compilation: if you indicate `-cp bin`, javac expects to find classes referenced in your sources in that directory. When running, you need to specify where your classes are located, unless they are right in the working directory (which is the default classpath, used if `-cp` is not given).

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. Thanks :)